# How can I store the front-end data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a rather broad question and not code-specific. I am looking for opinions that people who know how to implement this requirement

I am building a music application where people can queue music objects. A music object looks like

> ```
> url:
> name:
> views:
> ```

A user can queue this song for playing by clicking on the list. At this time I want to build a queue of music objects which then start playing. A very similar example is what grooveshark does:
[image]

I pretty much want to implement the same which has following capabilities

- Ability to persist queue even when browser is closed
- Ability to retrieve any queue if exists
- Ability to shuffle, force order on the objects in the queue to play

I am very new to this so have no idea where to store such data. Please help me understand what is that I need to learn to implement this.

Comment: You could stringify the data (turn it into a json string) and store it in localstorage. If the browser doesn't support localstorage, the only alternative would be server-side storage, I doubt cookies would offer enough storage for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather broad question! If you are developing a HTML5 application you may wish to investigate DOM storage facilities such as `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` (focusing mainly on `localStorage` for your needs/system requirements): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Here are some useful resources / info:

http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-storage/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/introduction-html5-domstorage-api-example/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=vs.85).aspx

Failing that you may want to look into cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie However I doubt `cookies` will provide you with what you need/want due to limitations in the amount you can store/save

Answer (score 2):

localstorage is your best bet

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

but you can polyfill and have it work with non-html5 browsers with this:

https://gist.github.com/350433

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK targeting only HTML5 browsers, you may want to look at something like this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage

Answer (score 0):

Since i could not see a requirement for older browser support i would recomend staying away from localStorage since it has some problem, like it's doing file IO and it's synchronous.

Instead you can have a look at indexedDB which is a bit harder to use, but better in every way as far as i know.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, `localStorage` is probably your best bet.. however you don't have to use it directly if you don't want to.  Check out AmplifyJS' `amplify.store`, which is a nice wrapper around `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` that's easy to use and uses feature detection to gracefully degrade on browsers that don't support localStorage (I forget what it uses instead, but it'll store your data.  Maybe cookies?)

Anyway, it's worth looking into.  http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) in the past for this purpose. It;s a nice plugin which provides a wrapper around the local storage where available and userData behavior in Internet Explorer older versions.